# Count query from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have 2 tables like this. For a given attribute (in table doc_attribute) and a given 'word' in file (in document), I want to find the count of distinct doc_id that do not contain that particular attribute but contain that 'word' in file.

For example if the attribute given is camera and  'word' is mobile, then the result should be 2. (ie., 2nd, 3rd and 5th doc_id does not contain camera and among them only 2nd and 3rd contain the 'word' mobile in file)

```
table doc_attribute
+--------+-----------+--------+
| doc_id | attribute | value  |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|     1 | product   | mobile |
|     1 | model     | lumia  |
|     1 | camera    | 5mp    |
|     2 | product   | mobile |
|     2 | model     | lumia  |
|     2 | ram       | 1gb    |
|     3 | product   | mobile |
|     3 | year      | 2014   |
|     3 | made-in   | china  |
|     4 | brand     | apple  |
|     4 | model     | iphone |
|     4 | camera    | 5mp    |
|     5 | product   | camera |
|     5 | brand     | canon  |
|     5 | price     | 20000  |



  table document
  +--------+-----------------------------+
  | doc_id | file                        |
  +--------+-----------------------------+
  |     1 | lumia 5mp mobile 1gb   2014  |
  |     2 | lumia 8mp mobile 1gb   2015  |
  |     3 | galaxy mobile fullhd 2gb     |
  |     4 | iphone apple 5mp 2013 new    |
  |     5 | canon 20000 new dslr 12mp    |
```

Current query:

```
select count(doc_id)
from document
where doc_id not in (select doc_id from doc_attribute
                     where attribute = 'camera')
  and file REGEXP '[[:<:]]mobile[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: Please post the SQL you have attempted first.

Comment: select count(doc_id) from document where doc_id not in(select doc_id from doc_attribute where attribute = 'camera') and file REGEXP '[[:<:]]mobile[[:>:]]';

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?  What does it return that is incorrect?  You might want to edit your original post to include both your query, and the results as well. Better than to add it in comments.

Comment: These are not my original tables. My original tables have too many rows and too much content in file. So it's difficult to check the results. Anyway the above query is giving wrong answer.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with the sample data you provided in your post?  Have you tested that?

Comment: Your original query looks correct and would return 2 with your sample data.

Comment: It may be correct with those but in my table its giving wrong values. I have 28 dictinct doc_id and all of them have attribute product and 18 file have word mobile in it. When i execute above query i need to get 0 but instead i get 10.

Comment: Then you really need to take the time to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, your question is not useful.

Comment: Be careful with "not in" queries, since "x not in (null)" returns null.  I prefer using "not exists" queries.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression and a left join will do it.

```
declare @attribute varchar(128), @word varchar(128)

SELECT @attribute='camera', @word='mobile'

SELECT count(DISTINCT document.id) Results
FROM document
LEFT JOIN doc_attribute
on document.id=doc_attribute.id AND doc_attribute.attribute=@attribute
WHERE doc_attribute.id IS NULL
AND file like '%'+@word+'%'
```